# I don't understand the logic of this statement "cur = prev->next;" in deleteall(key) function

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This program creates a linked list with insertion at the beginning and has a `deleteall(key)` function which would delete all the nodes having the key value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{

    int data;
    struct node* next; //creation a linked list with insertion at beginning
};

struct node* head = NULL;
int totaldeleted = 0;


void create(n) {

    int i;
    struct node *newnode, *temp;
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the data: ");
    scanf("%d", &newnode -> data);
    newnode -> next = NULL;

    if(head==NULL){
        head=newnode;    
    }

    temp = head;
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
        int data;
        newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter the data: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);

        newnode -> data = data;
        newnode -> next = NULL;

        newnode -> next = head;
        head = newnode;
    }
}

void display(){

    struct node* temp;
    printf("\nThe Linked list is: ");
    temp = head;

    while(temp!= NULL){
        printf("%d", temp -> data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }

}

int deleteall(key){ 

    struct node *prev, *cur;
    if(head == NULL){
        prev = NULL;
        cur = NULL;
        printf("\nList is empty!");
    }

    while(head != NULL && head->data == key){
        prev = head;
        head = head -> next;
        free(prev);
        totaldeleted++;   

    }
    prev = NULL;
    cur = head;

    while(cur != NULL){

        if(cur->data == key && prev != NULL){
               prev -> next = cur->next;
               free(cur);
               cur = prev->next; // I cannot understand this logic.
               totaldeleted++;
        }
        else {

         prev = cur;
        cur = cur -> next;

        }
    }
    return totaldeleted;
}

int main(){
    int n, key;

    printf("Enter the number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    create(n);
    display();
    printf("\nEnter the key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    totaldeleted = deleteall(key); 
    printf("Total deleted: %d", totaldeleted);
    display();

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: The statement " cur = prev->next;" what does this do and why do we need it here?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, that is not a specific problem description. If you don't get what the assignment does, you need to go over C and pointer basics. If you don't understand the algorithm at all, then again this is off-topic for [SO]. What is your *specific* misunderstanding? What did you do to try and figure it out, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: You are deleting an element. Therefore, the pointer `cur` now points to an invalid memory location. If you try to access the value stored in the pointer `cur`, you will get a program crash in the best case, and undefined behaviour in the worst one. To mitigate this problem, you either have to set `cur` to `nullptr` or to a valid memory address. In your case, you still want to use the list after deleting some elements. Therefore you reconnect the remaining elements back together by using `cur = prev->next`! As a side note: Why are you using linked lists? For studying? Or for actual code?

Comment: Thank You! @jan.sende. It for study.

Comment: @Shadab Ah that's okay then! :D In any case, have a look at: [Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before that line, `cur` points to the *deleted* node - this node was now freed so the value of `cur` pointer is indeterminate. We want to point `cur` to the node that *followed* the deleted node. Iff it wasn't deleted, we could get it from `cur->next`. However, `cur->next` is not valid. We could use a temporary variable to store the value of `cur->next` before the `free`...

However, prior to `free` there's this line:

```
prev -> next = cur->next;
```

i.e. the value we need has been assigned into `prev->next` now, hence we don't need a temporary variable, but can get it from `prev->next`.